# "GET /static/css/stylesheet.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1813

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates, static

I tried to ling CSS file in Django framework by using " "

### It shows error

but, it is showing error ""GET /static/css/stylesheet.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1813[file Oder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e9Kh.png)"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define `STATIC_URL` in `settings.py` like that:

```py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

and template file must be like that

```py
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/css/style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use following command after adding static files?

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```